# Javascript function to generate secret key

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering

I am looking for a way to generate a secret key in JavaScript.

I have a publicly exposed API that I only want to accept requests from my own app. My idea was to obfuscate a JavaScript function that generates an MD5 hash based on the endpoint and data of each request along with a datetime stamp that my backend can verify is a valid hash.

Since the hash is to to be generated per request I'm hoping it would be difficult for someone else to figure out how to request data from the server.
Obviously this is only used to prevent scraping or other apps using my API by incorporating important source files from my own app into the MD5 hash so that any changes to the code would cause an invalid hash to be generated.

This is only used for public requests... other non-public functionality will require a user to authenticate which will give them an API key to use.

How easy is it to reverse engineer a javascript function and can anyone else think of a better way to make it difficult for other apps to use my backend severs for querying data if my app is in the appstore?

Thanks

Comment: Well, even if the function is obfuscated, it's still easy to invoke, isn't it? And MD5 is far not the best hash.

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin I guess I wasn't expecting them to be able to invoke it as I was thinking of including some logic to contribute to the hash from source files in the app so if they change the app - invoking the function would not generate a valid hash. As for MD5... the hash would only be usable for that single request within a minute of that timestamp so I didn't think a weak hash was a problem.